# Is there a way to set one of these two incoherent instances as preferred?

Tags: haskell, types

I have this **class** at hand:

```
class C a b where
    f :: b -> a -> b
```

Along with it, I have coexist two **instances**.

The first instance works by applying elements from a foldable collection one by one:

```
instance (Foldable m, C a b) => C (m a) b where
    f = foldl f
```

The second conjoins two elements of a semigroup:

```
instance (Monoid a) => C a a where
    f = mappend
```

Of course, a type can be an instance of both `Monoid` and `Foldable` (example be `String`).

Since I presume `mappend` to be optimized for the case (i.e. there to be defined a way of conjoining the foldable collections at hand more efficient than transferring elements one by one), I want the compiler to **pick the second instance whenever possible**. How can I denote or enforce such preferrence?

Indeed, to have the code compile I have to specify these instances as `incoherent` which is right away false. As I see it, `C a a` is more specific since it only involves one variable type.

---

You can review the code on GitHub: [kindaro/overlap](https://github.com/kindaro/overlap).

Comment: No. (and 10 more characters)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Overlapping and incoherent instances are so confusing and fragile that they should be forbidden, IMO.

Comment: Think twice before using any extension with "incoherent" in the name. Then think thrice, then a fourth time, and then don't do it, because those extensions cause *way* too many problems.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, while this view is not common, I tend to consider `IncoherentInstances` somewhat superior to overlapping ones. In particular, you aren't allowed to care which instance is selected, so you're forced to make them (effectively) coherent. Instance chains/closed type families are better, but none of these techniques make much sense in this context.

Comment: "Indeed, to have the code compile I have to specify these instances as incoherent which is right away false. As I see it, C a a is more specific since it only involves one variable type."

Not really. There's no good heuristic to determine which instance is better - perhaps the first one covers more types despite two constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is a terrible idea. However, I think it's probably possible without `IncoherentInstances`, as long as you don't want any other instances.

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}
     (Foldable m, C a b, q ~ m a)
   => C q b where
  f = foldl f

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-}
         Monoid a => C a a where
  f = mappend
```

For more predictable behavior, you could even recast this to use a type family instead of overlapping instances, but it would still be a terrible idea. This class just doesn't make any sense.

```
*Class Data.Monoid> f (12 :: Sum Int) (ZipList [1,2,3 :: Sum Int])
Sum {getSum = 18}

*Class Data.Monoid> f [1,2,3:: Int] [12::Int]
[1,2,3,12]
```

Comment: This is a defeating example, but did you really have to call my idea silly?

Comment: @Kindaro, I'm known for coming up with peculiar names, but I can erase that one.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the compiler to pick the second instance whenever possible.

Easy. (But yes you need to take great care with overlapping instances; you definitely don't want `Incoherent`.)

Let's put the preferred instance first.

```
instance (Monoid a) => C a a where
    f = mappend

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} 
    C2 q b => C q b  where f = f2

class C2 a b where          -- identical to C
    f2 :: b -> a -> b

instance (Foldable m, C a b) => C2 (m a) b where
    f2 = foldl f
```

This is somewhat similar to @dfeuer's solution: put a catch-all `OVERLAPPABLE` instance. But the separate constraining instance for `C2` doesn't make any attempt to improve type `q` (there's no `~` constraint), so you've more freedom to add other instances: just make a chain of catch-alls `C3, C4, ...`.

Contra @dfeuer's comment: I advise never to use `INCOHERENT` -- you can always avoid it, per this answer. I also advise never to use `OVERLAPPING`, but only `OVERLAPPABLE`. Then the instance author acknowledges the responsibility to cater in advance for overlaps.