# Is it safe to use an overlappable catch-all instance in a method that counts nesting depth?

Tags: haskell

Consider method `g`:

```
class G a where
    g :: a -> Int

instance G a => G [a] where
    g [ ] = 1
    g xs = maximum (g <$> xs) + 1

instance G Void where
    g = absurd
```

```
λ g [[[]:: [Void]],[]]
3
```

It can be translated to work on nested lists of any fixed type, but I am having trouble making it polymorphic.

If I define a catch-all instance like this:

```
instance G a where
    g _ = 0
```

− It will overlap with `G a => G [a]`. I can allow this with "overlapping" and "overlappable" pragmas:

```
class G a where
    g :: a -> Int

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} G a => G [a] where
    g [ ] = 1
    g xs = maximum (g <$> xs) + 1

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} G a where
    g _ = 0
```

I tried a similar thing once and [got burned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124490/is-there-a-way-to-set-one-of-these-two-incoherent-instances-as-preferred), but I still did not learn the lesson.

My questions:

1. How can I determine whether this code is safe?
2. Is there a more likeable way to count nesting depth?

**P.S.** I just noticed that I accidentally specified "overlappable" to both instances of `G`. I did not notice at first because it actually seems to work this way. Which, if anything, makes the case even more alarming.

Comment: Is there any reason for using lists instead of trees, where a depth function would be much more natural, and require no type classes at all?

Comment: @chi I am investigating various ways to approach the cartesian product problem from [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48743657). A nested list would be preferable, for one, because it forces all branches to be of same depth. It is also related to the (not yet posed) question of making a type safe input of type-indexed vectors of variable length, as defined in [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49118438) and on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/188982). I'm looking for general understanding as well as a specific solution.

Comment: But your definition above does not make all branches to have the same depth, e.g. `[[], [[[[1]]]]]`. Are you sure you don't want to have `g ([] :: [[Int]]) = 2`, for instance?

Comment: @chi (1) There are branches to make up for the seemingly uneven depth, they're just invisible because they have zero elements. Hovewer humorous, this is the best answer I can give at the moment. (2) Maybe I should want this. It is logically more correct. It's definitely a valid objection to the current code. (3) Once I enforce that lists are never empty, both problems will go away.

Answer (score 3):

I propose that you use data rather than classes. So:

```
data FixedDepthTree a = Zero a | Succ (FixedDepthTree [a])

depth :: FixedDepthTree a -> Integer
depth (Zero _) = 0
depth (Succ t) = succ (depth t)
```

Comment: I appreciate your sharing with me of that trick. It is awesome. I will be keeping it in my sleeve. But it does not add to my understanding of things I am confused about, as related to the question.